# Function not doing anything after being called

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sorting

So I am making a program that calls functions to generate random numbers. Then calls a function to print those results. The second thing I want to print is the random numbers but after they are sorted in ascending order. After some tweaking with the ascending order function for an array, I try displaying it with my print function and nothing happens

Originally it did display as a second part of the output, but it didn't work and only showed 0's. Now I think I fixed the code but now it won't even display anything in the output so I have no way to check if its working and I am really confused as to why

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

#define lowerbound 10.0
#define upperbound 950.0
#define min_values 75
#define max_values 150
#define max_val_file 40
#define max_output 12

double randDouble();
int buildRandom(double array[]);
void print(string, double array[], int);
void sort(double array[], int);




int main()
{
    srand(19);
    
    
    int num_vals;
    double random_array[max_values];
    double sorted_array[max_values];
    
    string title1 = "Random Values";
    string title2 = "Sorted Random Values";
    
    
    num_vals = buildRandom(random_array);
    
  
    cout << "There are " << num_vals << " values in the first array" << '\n';
    
    
    print(title1, random_array, num_vals);
    
    sort(random_array, num_vals);
    
    cout << '\n';
    
    print(title2, sorted_array, num_vals);
    
    
}

double randDouble()
{
    int random_integer = rand();
    double random_value;
    
    random_value = lowerbound + (random_integer / (RAND_MAX / (upperbound - lowerbound)));
    
    return random_value;
}

int buildRandom(double random_array[])
{
    int num_vals = min_values + rand() % (max_values - min_values + 1);
    int i;
    double random_num;
    
    for (i = 0; i < num_vals; ++i)
    {
        random_num = randDouble();
        random_array[i] = random_num;
        
    }
    
    return num_vals;
    
    
}

void print(string title, double random_array[], int num_vals)
{
    int i;
    
    cout << '\n' << title << '\n' << '\n'<< setw(8);
    
    for (i = 0; i < num_vals; ++i)
    {
        cout << setprecision(3) << fixed << random_array[i] << setw(9);
        
        if ((i + 1) % max_output == 0)
        {
            cout << '\n' << setw(8);
        }
    }
    
}


void sort (double sorted_array[], int numberOfValues)
{
    int top = 0;
    int x, SSF, PTR;
    double swap;
    double last = numberOfValues - 1;
    
 
    
    for (top = 0; top < last; ++top)
    {
        PTR = top;
        SSF = top;
        for (x = 0; PTR < last; ++x)
        {
            
            if (sorted_array[PTR] < sorted_array[SSF])
            {
                SSF = PTR;
            }
        }
        
        swap = sorted_array[SSF];
        sorted_array[SSF] = sorted_array[top];
        sorted_array[top] = swap;
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], with emphasis on the *minimal* part.

Comment: The sort function is an endless loop. `for (x = 0; PTR < last; ++x)` never finishes because `PTR` never changes inside the loop.